# Read and store data with the usb

Tags: usb, atmega2560, makefile

Hi i am new to Arduino and I want to know if it is possible to read the data from a sensor that it is connected to the Arduino, I am using the Arduino mega 2560, which is already working, as I have a LED which change color depending on the detection of the object and then store it in a file as txt or another normal extension.

Comment: You need to edit this question to be more specific about what you are asking.  A typical Arduino can report data back to a *USB host* such as a PC (typically actually through a serial port like channel, although the transport is USB), however at least the ATmega-based ones are unable to act as hosts themselves, which means that they cannot directly write data to a *USB device* such as a flash drive.

Comment: That's correct.  I use Arduinos of many flavors to write data out their serial port, and have a Python program on  the PC side waiting for data on /dev/ttyUSB0 (for example).  That works fine.  Please take the tour at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/Tour then come back and edit this question to be more specifically about the Arduino.  You are welcome here.  But this question is in danger of being closed as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have experience with Processing, but probably that is what you need. It communicates through USB and with the CreateWriter function, you can create a text file.

More about Processing can be found at [Processing](https://processing.org/)

Also another thread at Electronics stack exchange might help:

[Related question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/54/saving-arduino-sensor-data-to-a-text-file)

Alternatives (also mentioned in the above thread):

- Use serial port directly with a terminal application on the PC
- Use an SD card inside the Arduino to log

Comment: Thanks I would want to do that with the serial port directly with a terminal application as putty or the Arduino serial monitor.

Comment: Than just copy the content to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, you want to store the data displayed in the Serial monitor to a text file or something similar. As the Arduino itself cannot do this task, I used "GoBetwino" to save my data from an Arduino into a text file, from where you can export the data into Excel if you want charts and graphs. The process is fairly easy and described properly in their user manual. 
https://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/GoBetwino